# selecting more than one row of matching data

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select the number (cid) of a customer that has rented the same movie from 2 different branches.  My tables are as follows:

```
RENTED
(cid, copyid)
12345  99999
12345  88888

COPY
(copyid, mid, bid)
99999    444  123
88888    444  456
```

So one customer (12345) has rented the same move (444) from two different branches (123, 456).  I am not sure how to compare the values where in two different records, the values mid = mid but bid != bid.  I tried to use 'some' and 'all' but this gives me no rows (code below)

```
select cid
from rented R join copy CP on R.copyid = CP.copyid
where CP.mid = all (select mid from copy where CP.mid = copy.mid) and CP.bid != some (select bid 
from copy where CP.bid = copy.bid);
```

and my output should be

```
cid
12345
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the `HAVING` clause. The following query will list all customers who have ever rented the same movie several times:

```
SELECT r.cid
  FROM rented r
  JOIN copy p ON r.copyid = p.copyid
 GROUP BY r.cid, p.mid
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.bid) > 1
```

Comment: This does not meet the requirement that the bid must be different for two rows.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: with @OMG Ponies' update the query should meet your requirement :) thx

Answer (score 0):

Using a single pass on each table:

select distinct(cid) from (
  select cid, count(bid) over (partition by r.cid,c.mid) dist_branch
  from rented r, copy c
  where r.copyid = c.copyid)
where dist_branch > 1;